# Laravel return collection as key/value automatically?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my app I have a key/value pair of permissions in a table that is set as a `hasMany` to my users:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Permissions');
}
```

Rather than a collection with just an array I would like it returned as a key value array so that I can just access the permissions like:

```
$user->permissions->blah;
```

I tried doing some post processing but when I modified the `permissions` attribute directly or created a new one `perms` it than treated it as a modified attribute which messes up any actual saves I may need to do.

Is there a way to accomplish this on the fly or have some hook within the `Permission` or `User` model directly?

Answer (score 3):

Yes Correct.

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

```
  /**
         * Dynamically retrieve attributes on the model.
         *
         * @param  string  $key
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function __get($key)
        {
            return $this->getAttribute($key);
        }


public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $inAttributes = array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes);

        // If the key references an attribute, we can just go ahead and return the
        // plain attribute value from the model. This allows every attribute to
        // be dynamically accessed through the _get method without accessors.
        if ($inAttributes || $this->hasGetMutator($key))
        {
            return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
        }

        // If the key already exists in the relationships array, it just means the
        // relationship has already been loaded, so we'll just return it out of
        // here because there is no need to query within the relations twice.
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->relations))
        {
            return $this->relations[$key];
        }

        // If the "attribute" exists as a method on the model, we will just assume
        // it is a relationship and will load and return results from the query
        // and hydrate the relationship's value on the "relationships" array.
        if (method_exists($this, $key))
        {
            return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key);
        }
    }
```

Actually

$user->permissions equal $user->permissions()->get()

If you want to do post process let create a new function like:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($value);
    }
```

OR

```
public function getPasswordAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['password'] ;
    }
```

Comment: Nice Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model @tek

Answer (score 0):

This function is for creating Eloquent relationships.

If you want to get custom responses then you need to create new method that returns values exactly like you want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

**Attribute Accessor**

Here is how I would do it. First create a protected/private data member on the model to hold the key/value pairs. This will prevent Eloquent from attempting to save this as model attribute.

```
protected $permValues = [];
```

Next create an [attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) so that we can build they key/value array if it doesn't yet exist.

```
public getPermissionValuesAttribute()
{
    if (empty($this->permValues))
    {
        $this->permValues = $this->permissions->lists('value', 'key');
    }

    return $this->permValues;
}
```

This makes things almost as you'd like them to be.

```
$model->permissionValues['blah'];
```

**Magic Methods**

You can take this a step further by creating a class to hold the permission set and defining [__set and __get](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) magic methods.

```
protected $permSet;

public getPermissionSetAttribute()
{
    if (empty($this->permSet))
    {
        $this->permSet = new PermissionSet($this->permissions);
    }

    return $this->permSet;
}
```

I'll let you fill in the blanks on the PermissionSet class but the end result would work exactly as you'd like it to.

```
$model->permissionSet->blah;
```